# Add #N/A and a number from other cell

Tags: excel-2010

I need to add three cells in excel 2010, for example:

val1 = 1

val2 = 3

### val3 = #N/A

sum = 4

As you can see, I need the result to be a number, not #N/A.
I would like #N/A to count as 0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself, but L42 pointed me into the right direction.

In my table, data is located in J2, K2 and L2 and the sum is in M2 where I entered the final formula: **=IFERROR(J2;0)+IFERROR(K2;0)+IFERROR(L2;0)**

which basically means that I have manually added the 3 cells but checked for errors first, for each cell, with the function iferror and returned 0 if error exists.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(A1:A3),0,A1:A3))
```

Entered as `Array Formula` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in Cell `A4` assuming your data is in `Column A`.
Change the address otherwise.

Comment: thank you, you pointed me in the right direction and helped me to solve it myself.